# How can I detect Workrave windows?

Tags: wmctrl, workrave

I have some scripts using xmacro. The problem is the thing that Workrave blocks the input from a keyboard for Micro-breaks. So I would like to pause my xmacro script at the moment when Micro-break window appear. The problem is that Workrave is not "normal" window and it is not possible to see it with `wmctrl -l`. So the question is how can I detect that Micro-break window is visible?

[image]